# why html5 canvas is not full screen when vertical scrollbar appears

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm using a full screen canvas as background of the first section of my page. But as soon as I add the second section and vertical scrollbar appears, the height of canvas reduces a little bit and a gap appears. here's my code:
P.S: Sorry, my code contained bugs, I fixed them. now you can see the red gap.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var c = canvas.getContext('2d')

scaleCanvas()
window.addEventListener("resize", scaleCanvas)

function scaleCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight
    c.fillStyle = 'black'
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#first-section {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: red; /* to see the gap */
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#second-section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
}

#canvas {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-section">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
<div id="second-section"></div>
```

Comment: can you add some more code?, here I can't see the problem You specified

Comment: Which browser? In Firefox, I get both a vertical and horizontal scrollbar but only at larger view sizes.

Comment: Is your code right? I see id="first-section" but only .first-section in the CSS. It would be good if you could make a working snippet which shows the problem.

Comment: @AHaworth you're right, I'm sorry for that mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean full screen, and not full page. The two are very different.

If you mean full page then the link to the [Screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen) API will also give you details on obtaining the page size.

### Size full screen canvas.

The problem is that you have content that extends outside the page width and height (`innerWidth`, `innerHeight`)

The elements with ids `first-section`, `content`, and `second-section` must be inside the display area or else you will get a scroll bar. The scroll bar will change the `innerWidth`, `innerHeight` values subtracting the scrollbar width or height depending on which is visible.

To prevent scroll bars the best option is to keep all content inside `innerWidth`, and `innerHeight`

### Full screen with scroll bars.

If you want have the scroll bars and you are using full screen you can use the [Screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen) API to get the `width` and `height` of the display in  pixels. You can set the canvas size to match the screen without the scroll bars effecting its size.

**Note** Do read the provided link to [Screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen) as what defines the screen may not be as expected. EG more than one monitor, or device orientation will effect how you use the API.

### Basic example

Thus when in full-screen mode you can set the canvas size and ignore scroll bars with

```
function sizeFullScreenCanvas() {
  canvas.width = screen.width;
  canvas.height= screen.height;
}
```